# The message embedded in the least significant bit plane of the gray image encoded using Hamming code 7.4

Tags: matlab, hamming-code, lsb

Hi guys I work on LSB stenography using hamming code.
The whole code should work so that the image changes to gray, the message is encoded with a Hamming code and inserted into the LSB bit plane, then the whole image is assembled and extracted and decoded from the encoded message from the image.
I dont know solve this error on 52 line if I move everything on 52 line up then again I get an error with bin_num_message because the program does not recognize such a variable.  I will be very happy for any help or advice.

```
% Clear the existing workspace
clear all;

% Clear the command window
clc;

% Read the input image
input = imread('lena.bmp');

% Convert image to grayscale
input=rgb2gray(input);

% Resize the image to required size
input=imresize(input, [512 512]);

% Message to be embedded
message = 'A';

% Length of the message where each character is 8 bits
len = length(message) * 8;

% Get all the ASCII values of the characters of the message
ascii_value = uint8(message);

% Convert the decimal values to binary
bin_message = transpose(dec2bin(ascii_value, 8));

% Get all the binary digits in separate row
bin_message = bin_message(:);

% Length of the binary message
N = length(bin_message);

% Converting the char array to numeric array
bin_num_message=str2num(bin_message);

% Hamming (7,4) encoding function
function [encoded_msg]=Hamming74Encode(input_msg)
data = reshape(input_msg,4,[]).';
G = [1 0 1 0 1 1 0;0 1 1 0 0 1 1;1 1 0 1 0 0 1];
encoded_msg = mod(data*G,2);
encoded_msg = encoded_msg(:).';
end

% Hamming (7,4) decoding function
function [decoded_msg]=Hamming74Decode(input_msg)
H = [1 0 1 0 1 1 0;0 1 1 0 0 1 1;1 1 0 1 0 0 1];
decoded_msg = mod(input_msg*H',2);
end

% Encode the binary message using Hamming (7,4) encoding
encoded_bin_message = Hamming74Encode(bin_num_message);

% Initialize output as input
output = input;

% Get height and width for traversing through the image
height = size(input, 1);
width = size(input, 2);

% Counter for number of embedded bits
embed_counter = 1;

% Traverse through the image
for i = 1 : height
for j = 1 : width
      % If more bits are remaining to embed
    if(embed_counter <= length(encoded_bin_message))

        % Finding the Least Significant Bit of the current pixel
        LSB = mod(double(input(i, j)), 2);

        % Find whether the bit is same or needs to change
        temp = double(xor(LSB, encoded_bin_message(embed_counter)));

        % Updating the output to input + temp
        output(i, j) = input(i, j)+temp;

        % Increment the embed counter
        embed_counter = embed_counter + 1;
    end

end
end

% Reading the data back from image
embedded_data = [];
for i = 1 : height
for j = 1 : width
    if (embed_counter <= length(encoded_bin_message))

 % Finding the Least Significant Bit of the current pixel
        LSB = mod(double(output(i, j)), 2);

        % Find whether the bit is same or needs to change
        temp = double(xor(LSB, encoded_bin_message(embed_counter)));

        % Updating the output to input + temp
        output(i, j) = input(i, j) + temp;

        % Increment the embed counter
        embed_counter = embed_counter + 1;
    end
end
end

% Reading the data back from image
embedded_data = [];
for i = 1 : height
for j = 1 : width
% Finding the Least Significant Bit of the current pixel
LSB = mod(double(output(i, j)), 2);
embedded_data = [embedded_data LSB];
end
end

% Extracting the encoded message from embedded data
encoded_data = embedded_data(1:N*7);

% Decode the encoded binary message using Hamming (7,4) decoding
decoded_bin_message = Hamming74Decode(reshape(encoded_data, 7, [])');

% Get the indices where error occurs
error_index = find(decoded_bin_message >= 4);

% If no error is there in the decoded message
if isempty(error_index)
decoded_bin_message = decoded_bin_message(:).';
else
% Correcting the error in the decoded message
for i = 1 : length(error_index)
decoded_bin_message(error_index(i)) = bitxor(decoded_bin_message(error_index(i)), 7);
end
decoded_bin_message = decoded_bin_message(:).';
end

% Convert the decoded binary message to ASCII values
decoded_num_message = bin2dec(reshape(decoded_bin_message, 8, [])');

% Convert the decimal values to characters
decoded_message = char(decoded_num_message);

% Display the decoded message
disp(decoded_message);

% Write the output image
imwrite(output, 'output.bmp');

% Display the original image
figure;
imshow(input);
title('Original Image');

% Display the output image
figure;
imshow(output);
title('Steganographed Image');
```

This is error after run this program:
Error: File: spustac.m Line: 52 Column: 1 Function definitions in a script must appear at the end of the file. Move all statements after the "Hamming74Decode" function definition to before the first local function definition.

Comment: The error message you're getting is pretty explicit, please follow its guidance and then [edit] your question to include the latest error. You might need to add a breakpoint and debug your script, you'll probably see that you need to add missing inputs to the functions, as variables defined in the script are not automatically visible within the local functions

Comment: God this looks like an AI-generated mess. The function definitions in Matlab need to be at the end of the code. Move the function definitions to the bottom.

Comment: @Kylar Code is mine. I just use AI because I dont know implement hamming code on the message. Thanks for your answer. I try to move the function definitions to the bottom but after doing this I just got more errors. do you know of any hamming code function in matlab that I could use for my steganography?